Is there any examples of a ERC20 token with default multisig functions?
I'm working in a project which  uses a token to trace green energy. Energy plants should be able to mint them in conjuction in a multisig. I know I can use a multisig wallet in conjuction with a ERC20 token, but I would like to use a custom token which has native multisig requerements for minting, to be all performed in the same transactions?
Any examples on similar concepts or advices for the contract?
